# How to make same center for main window and its navigated pages in wpf navigation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

We are working on WPF application which has MainWindow. From main window we are calling NavigationWindow.

```
NavigationWindow nav = new NavigationWindow();
nav.Content = new Page1();
```

After this we are navigating to page2 from page1 using

```
NavigationService.NavigationService navigationService = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
navigationService.Navigate(new Page2());
```

Our issue is page alignment. We want same center for Mainwindow and Page2.

1. We already tried using WindowStartupLocation as CenterScreen/CenterOwner/Manual.
2. We also tried Top and left margin.
   We need a generic solution not system specific.

Comment: _"We already tried using WindowStartupLocation as CenterScreen/CenterOwner/Manual"_ -- and what did that code do? Why wasn't that what you wanted? Please fix your question so it includes a good [mcve], showing the closest to correct result you were able to get, and explain in more detail why the normal ways of solving the problem aren't working. See also [ask] for more details on how to present a clear, answerable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NavigationWindow nav = new NavigationWindow(); 
nav.Content = new Page1();

nav.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;

var screenW = 
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth; 
var windowW = nav.Width; 
var xAxis = 0; 

if ((screenW - windowW)>0) 
{
xAxis = Convert.ToInt32((screenW - windowW) / 2); 
}

nav.Left = xAxis;        //Left position to set window at centre else to the left


nav.Top = (System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight /8);
```

//Fixed top positio

```
nav.ShowDialog();
```